# For google chrome extension development, is it possible to set a download location?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

As the question says, can an extension save files to a user-set location for all future downloads (that differs from the download location set in preferences)?

If so, how would this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=12133) for a lengthy discussion on the matter. Per the last qualitative entry on 8.10.2012:

> The downloads ui is a very sensitive part of chrome from a security
>   perspective, so it is unlikely that we will ever be able to allow
>   extensions to completely replace chrome's downloads ui. We have plans
>   to allow extensions to *extend* chrome://downloads in a limited and
>   safe way, and extensions may *add* browser action buttons, but
>   replacing the downloads ui entirely is not likely in the foreseeable
>   future. Witness the search engine hijacking security issues. With the
>   --disable-downloads-shelf flag, extensions could suggest that users set that flag.
>
> Please also feel free to write a download manager extension as a
>   browser action to demonstrate a better ui. If a download manager
>   extension gains sufficient popularity, we may consider adopting
>   something like it as chrome's native downloads ui. That's a more
>   likely way that extensions could replace the ui, but slower and safer.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer.

Comment: @AaronAAA No problem, sorry it wasn't a more positive one :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you can't. It would be a security issue if plugins had such abilities.